# Assigning procs to constants

Tags: ruby, lambda, constants, proc

I found that procs and lambdas can be used as a substitute for short methods and helper modules. I put methods that don't belong anywhere else into a file that is just a list of procs assigned to constants. For example, a file `helper_procs.rb` is required by `init.rb`, and contains the following:

```
RED_TEXT = proc{|t| "\e[31m#{t}\e[0m"} 
GREEN_TEXT = proc{|t| "\e[32m#{t}\e[0m"}
YELLOW_TEXT = proc{|t| "\e[33m#{t}\e[0m"}

CURRENT_TIME = proc do
  date = Time.now.to_s.split(' ')[0].split('-').reverse.join('-')
  time = Time.now.to_s.split(' ')[1]; "#{time} (#{date})"
end
```

and then, anywhere in the program (in a different file), I do:

```
puts GREEN_TEXT["A string!"]
puts CURRENT_TIME.call
```

Is it bad practice? Are there pitfalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bad practice. Defining constants on the main level is as bad as using global variables. That defeats the purpose of object oriented programming (OOP). In OOP, you want to hide unnecessary things as much as possible. If something always works on a string, then that should not be accessible outside of the context of a string, and that should be defined on the `String` class. If something always provides some form of a time, then that should be defined on the `Time` class, either as a class or an instance method depending on the nature of the method.

Comment: While in a perfect world I'd agree with you, monkeypatching isn't good either, and that's what you're suggesting. Also, top level constants are not as bad as global variables. Also, just to be a Ruby nitpick, top-level modules in which you put your constants are constants. Ha. ;)

Comment: Ruby encourages monkey patching. If that is a problem, that is what refinements are for. By constants, I meant constants other than modules.

Comment: I know. I was nitpicking. On a more serious note, though, until refinements came along, monkeypatching was frowned on in libraries and large codebases.

Comment: Because Rails is a whole new environment for your app. For smaller libraries that actually have to work with other libraries or don't have the luxury of everyone else making their stuff work with it, not monkeypatching could be rather important.

Comment: So in essence I should do something like class String def red_text and then "\e[31m#{self}\e[0m"?